# Are there nonabelian groups $G$ s.t. $G=\langle a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}\mid a_i^2=\epsilon,\epsilon^2=1,a_ia_j=\epsilon a_ja_i \textrm{ for }i\ne j\rangle.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, finitely-generated

I study a proof of Hurwitz's theorem on bilinear compositions of sums of squares. The proof relies on the following lemma (which is given as an exercise):

**Lemma.** Let $G=\langle a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}\mid a_i^2=\epsilon,\epsilon^2=1,a_ia_j=\epsilon a_ja_i \textrm{ for }i\ne j\rangle.$ Then

- $|G|=2^n;$
- $[G,G]=\langle1,\epsilon\rangle;$
- $Z(G)=\{1,\epsilon\}$ for odd $n$ and $Z(G)=\{1,\epsilon,a_1\dots a_{n-1},\epsilon a_1\dots a_{n-1}\}$ for even $n.$

It is clear that $\epsilon\in Z(G),$ so $H=\{1,\epsilon\}$ is normal in $G.$ Since $G/H$ is Abelian, either $[G,G]=\{1\}$ (and, hence, $G$ is Abelian and $\epsilon=1$) or $[G,G]=\{1,\epsilon\}.$

$G/H$ is a direct product of $n-1$ copies of $\mathbb Z_2,$ consequently, $|G/H|=2^{n-1}.$ And to prove the first two statements it's enough to check that for $n>2$ there exists a non-Abelian group with those relations.

Here I'm stuck. Could you please help me?

**UPD:** I see there's no need to construct such a group to gain a proof but this question (i.e., the existence of this group) has intrigued me on it's own.

Comment: This $G$ is a central extension of $C_2^{n-1}$ by $C_2$. In general central extensions of a group $G$ by an abelian group $A$ can be constructed via a suitable multiplication on $G \times A$ and from that construction all of these properties are straightforward to verify.

Comment: $G$ can be realized as the set of $2^n$ words of the form
$$\epsilon^{k_0}a_1^{k_1}\dots a_{n-1}^{k_{n-1}},\quad k_0,\dots,k_{n-1}\in\{0,1\},$$
equipped with the binary operation dictated by the relations.

Comment: Simplest example is the quaternion group, of order eight, generated by $i,j$ with $i^2=j^2=-1$, $ij=-ji$.

Comment: Note: this is about a *presentation*, not a **re**presentation.